# Issue when imoporting GDAL : ImportError, Library not loaded, Image not found

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, gdal

Since yesterday I struggle to import some libraries such as GDAL (or iris) and I allways get the same type of outputs.

```
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gdal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "gdal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(./_gdal.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.56.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/zoran/anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I searched in my files and found:

- 1 files containing `libicui18n`
- 2 files containing `_gdal.so`

  /Users/zoran/anaconda/pkgs/icu-54.1-0/lib/libicui18n.54.1.dylib

  /Users/zoran/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so

  /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so

This morning I could import gdal without problem and suddenly (I don't know what I did) it was totally impossible.

I tried to:
- uninstall/install gdal
- uninstall/install anaconda and install again gdal
- create different new environments (in python2 and python3) and install only gdal

I don't know what this `libicui18n.56.dylib` is, neighter `libgdal.20.dylib`.

When I type otool -L with the name of the paths above I get:

```
libicui18n.54.dylib (compatibility version 54.0.0, current version 54.1.0)
@loader_path/./libicuuc.54.dylib (compatibility version 54.0.0, current version 54.1.0)
@loader_path/./libicudata.54.dylib (compatibility version 54.0.0, current version 54.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

@rpath/libgdal.1.dylib (compatibility version 20.0.0, current version 20.5.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/GDAL (compatibility version 22.0.0, current version 22.1.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

When I type conda info:

```
           platform : osx-64
      conda version : 4.2.9
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.9
conda-build version : 2.0.2
     python version : 2.7.12.final.0
   requests version : 2.11.1
   root environment : /Users/zoran/anaconda  (writable)
default environment : /Users/zoran/anaconda
   envs directories : /Users/zoran/anaconda/envs
      package cache : /Users/zoran/anaconda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/osx-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/osx-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/noarch/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
        config file : /Users/zoran/.condarc
       offline mode : False
```

I am wondering if somehow the libraries are saved in the wrong directrory?

I've seen many similar issues but no trick to fix the problem.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem.

```
conda install -f jpeg=8

conda install libgdal
```

solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/111).

Thank you for the clear explanation of "ocefpaf":

> You problem seems like the usuall mismatch between conda-forge and
>   defaults. Can you try the following instructions (if you do want to
>   use conda-forge's gdal of course):
>
> 1. Make sure you have the latest conda to take advantage of the channel preference feature. You can do that by issuing conda update
>      conda in the root env of your conda installation.
> 2. Edit your .condarc file and place the conda-forge on top of defaults. The .condarc usually lives in your home directory. See mine
>      below. (Note that the more channels you have you are more likely to
>      face issues. I recommend having only defaults and conda-forge.)
> 3. Issue the following commands to check if you will get the correct installation:

```
conda create --yes -n TEST_GDAL python=3.5 gdal
source activate TEST_GDAL
python -c "from osgeo import gdal; print(gdal.__version__)"
```

> If you get 2.1.1 you got a successful installation of the latest
>   version from conda-forge. We always recommend users to work with envs
>   as the the example above. But you do not need to use Python 3.5
>   (conda-forge has 3.4 and 2.7 also) and you do not need to name the env
>   TEST_GDAL.
>
> And here is my .condarc file.

```
> cat .condarc
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
show_channel_urls: true
```